# Can anyone explain me the solutions of this $|x-5| + |x+6| = 11$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have an intuition of this using number line but I want to know what mathematics goes into solving these type of problems.

Answer (score 3):

Just do cases.

Either $(x-5) \ge 0$ or $(x-5) < 0$.  And either $(x+6)\ge 0$ or $(x+6) < 0$.

So you have four cases

1. $x-5 \ge 0; x+6 \ge 0$ and so $|x-5| = x-5$ and $|x+6| = x+6$ and you have the equation $(x+5) + (x-6) = 11$.
2. $x-5 \ge 0; x+6 < 0$ and so $|x+6| = -(x+6)$ and you have the equation $(x-5)-(x-6)=11$.

And so on.

But make sure your solutions *agree* with your initial assumptions.

And if you get an impossible answer.... that's okay; it just means your assumptions were impossible.

And you make get an answer that doesn't tell you anything about $x$.  If that answer is a true statement that just means $x$ can be anything so long as your assumptions are true.

....

That's brute force method that works.

There are some sophisticated things.

$|x-5|$ is the distance that $x$ is from $5$.  And $|x+6|$ is the distance $x$ is from $-6$.

Now the distance the distance from $5$ to $-6$ is $11$.

So if $x < -6$ then the distance $x$ is from $5$ is more than $11$.

And if $x > 5$ the distance $x$ is from $-6$ is more than $11$.

So $-6\le x < 5$.

Then the distance $x$ is from $-6$ is $x+6$ and the distance $x$ is from $5$ is $5-x$.

So $|x-5| + |x+6| = (5-x) + (6 + x) = 11$.  solving we get $11 = 11$.... which is *always* true.  So $x$ can be anything so that $-6 \le x \le 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Try different cases, for example,

when x>5 and x<6;

when x<5;

when x>6.

Substitute the expression for the absolute value in each case, solve the resultant linear equation (if it exists) and then verify whether these are in the bounds of your assumptions.

Comment: You meant the two values to check  are -6 and 5, right?

Answer (score 0):

The root of $x-5=0$ and $x+6=0$ are $5,-6$ respectively. And these two roots partition the reals into $3$ regions: $(-\infty,-6]\cup(-6,5]\cup (5,\infty)$, and you can consider the equation in each region at a time and combine all solutions you obtain. Note that $-6,5$ are the solutions already.

Answer (score 0):

Considering,

Either $(x−5)\geq0$ or $(x−5)\leq0$. And either $(x+6)\geq0$ or $(x+6)\leq0$.

$\therefore$ We have the following four cases,

$1.$ $(x−5)\geq0$ and $(x+6)\geq0$, not possible as numbers above $5$ don't fulfill the condition.

$2.$ $(x−5)\geq0$ and $(x+6)\leq0$, not possible as numbers above $5$ don't fulfill the condition and numbers less than $-6$ don't fulfill the condition

$3.$ $(x−5)\leq0$ and $(x+6)\geq0$, absolutely possible and true.

$4.$ $(x−5)\leq0$ and $(x+6)\leq0$, not possible as numbers below $-6$ don't fulfill the condition.

Thus , we observe that $(x−5)\leq0$ and $(x+6)\geq0$ is the solution to our problem.

You could also try using graphs to find the solution. I am giving one graph here,
[image: Graph of the equation]

Answer (score 0):

A geometric way to look at this problem is to consider the inequality version in a lifted space and the set thus defined, i.e.
$$\{(x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : |x_1 - 5| + |x_2 - (-6)| \le 11,\; x_1 = x_2\}$$
This defines the intersection of $B_1 := \{(x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : |x_1 - 5| + |x_2 - (-6)| \le 11\}$ with the line $x_1=x_2$.

If you have heard of $\ell_1$-norm, then $B_1$ is nothing but the ball centered at $(5,-6)$ with radius $11$ in this norm, which takes a diamond shape (i.e. a box rotated 90 degrees). It's a good exercise to try to draw it. Then intersect $B_1$ with the line $x_1 - x_2=0$ gives the solution.

Intersecting a line with an $\ell_1$-ball in two dimensions may have one, two, or infinite number of solutions. In your case, I think there are infinite number of solutions, because every point on the line segment $(-6,-6)$ to $(5,5)$ is a solution, i.e. every $x\in [-6,5]$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1: Let $|y|=|x-5|\Rightarrow x=y+6$, we have:

$|y|+|y+5+6|=11$

This is possible only if $y=0$, hence we have:

$|x-5|=0\Rightarrow |x|=5$

which gives $0\leq x\leq 5$ and $-5\leq x\leq 0$

2: Let $|y|=|x+6|\Rightarrow  x=y-6$, we have:

$|y-6-5|+|y|=11\Rightarrow |y-11|+|y|=11$

This is possible only if $y=0\Rightarrow x=-6\Rightarrow |x|=6$ and we have:

$-6\leq x \leq 0$

So solutions in general is:

$-6\leq x \leq 0$

$0\leq x\leq 5$